# Memory not compatible with motherboard?

Tags: windows-7, windows, memory, motherboard, bsod

I've been getting BSODS on my computer and have tried everything that I can think of to find out what's causing...

My motherboards memory compatibility list is: http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/X79%20Extreme6/?cat=Memory

My memory is: http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B00GU9UASM/ which is module: CMY64GX3M8A2133C11

It's not on the list of compatible memory, however if I do the following:

- Put 4 sticks of memory into DIMM slots 1-4 the computer works fine.
- Put 4 sticks of memory into DIMM slots 5-8 the computer BSOD's

So obviously with all 8 sticks in place the computer BSODS every hour or so

A copy of the minidumps can be downloaded: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/vdr6gampskjrnc8/AABVazZZsHAkEjV_rqxwRBD6a?dl=0

Anyone know if it's incompatible memory or something broken with the motherboard?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wh90W.png]

- Options 1-3 work fine
- Options 4-6 fail to work (the screens just don't turn on for some reason)
- Option 7 and 8 work fine (Unusual because it uses slots DIMM5 and and DIMM7 which which fail in option 4-6)
- Option 9 boots fine but it causes lots of random BSOD issues.

Comment: Have you done memtest? That should be your first step if you suspect the memory modules or slots faulting. If modules are fine (try reorder) then replace the MOBO as it might have a faulty slots. Hey - it happens.

Comment: I did memtest86+ for 24 hours and it returned no errors... I'm gonna put 4 more sticks of memory in 1 by 1 to try and find a faulty slot and then call up asrock if this is the case

Comment: It requires more than 24 hours to test the quantity of memory you have in your system.  If you only use 5-8 what happens?

Comment: When adding in more modules the timings could need tweaking, take for example XMP profiles that work fine with small ammounts of memory, and worked fine with 2 chips, but people have more trouble with this higher speed when using 4. Assuming there is nothing wrong with the sticks or the sockets, you could try reducing the speed, or increasing the numbers on the timings (adding wait states) prior to putting more in. I don't know asrock but some boards do what is called memory training (post, tweaking it when it fails) But will not do it with some Fast Boot options enabled

Comment: Are you putting the same sticks in roughly the same slots every time? (e.g.: Sticks 1-4 always going in slots 1-4.) Try only running with two sticks, in the first two slots, at a time. If those work fine for a day, swap in two different ones. Keep going until you hit a BSOD. Then, take out one stick and set it aside. Replace that stick with one that tested good earlier. If you hit a BSOD, you know which one's your problem. If you don't hit a BSOD, swap the other stick back in and see what happens.

Comment: @Iszi I tried the same four sticks from 1-4 in 5-8 and while it worked fine in 1-4 it BSODed in 5-8. I've got a stick in 1-4 and also 6 at the moment (I think 5 might be faulty), I'm gonna try 7 and 8 before trying 5 again. Current uptime is 1 hour 25 mins which means if 6 is faulty it should BSOD very soon.

Comment: Wow, if it's true and your memory isn't compatible with motherboard, you try to get back memory where bought it. Otherwise there is an opportunity that your motherboard can be spoiled of using in it such memory.

Comment: If you look at my amazing illustration: http://i.imgur.com/eQXKn47.png you can see options 1-4 work fine, but option 5-7 fail to work, but option 8 creates BSODS and option 9-10 are untested (it boots, but I don't know about BSODS YET)

Comment: How are 1 & 2 different? Looks like only 1-4 filled in on both.

Comment: @Iszi My bad, this is the uptodate version: http://i.imgur.com/OELal4w.png